# Find the points on the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=1$ where the tangent line has slope $1$.

Tags: calculus

I did the following:

$$2x+4y\cdot y'=0\\y'=\frac{-2x}{4y}$$

Now I guess I should take all pairs $(x,y)$ such that:

$$\frac{-2x}{4y}=1$$

And I found: $\left(1,-\cfrac{1}{2}\right),\left(-1,\cfrac{1}{2}\right)$

And then I tried to do:

$$x^2+2y^2=1\\ y=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

And then derive $\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}$, this yielded the pairs: $\{(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}),(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})\}$

I don't see what I did wrong in the implicit differentiation method.

Comment: How did you get the two points?

Comment: Your two points, $\left(1, -\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\\left(-1, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ are NOT on the ellipse!

Comment: From your derivative, rewrite as $-2x/4=y$ and then substitute this back into the equation for your ellipse to get actual points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the equation $1=\frac{-2x}{4y}$ which is equivalent to $x=-2y$. Now, the points you are looking for should be on the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=1$ so you have the additional constraint:
$$(-2y)^2+2y^2=1 \;\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;\;y^2=1/6.$$
Therefore, $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$. In turn, $x=-2y=\mp\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}$, so the two points you want are
$$
(\sqrt{6}/3,-\sqrt{6}/6)\;\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;\;(-\sqrt{6}/3,\sqrt{6}/6)
$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $x=-2y$ and we get $$4y^2+2y^2=1$$ thus we get $$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\pm(1,-\frac 1 2)$ was wrong, any multiple was obeying as well : solution is within a line. Then find intersection with the ellipse.

In particular, the other answer you found obey the relation ( with factor=  $\sqrt{ \frac 3 2}$)